# Separate out yearly data from a set of data spanning several years

Tags: matlab, compare

I have a column vector of dates and a column vector of data. The dates range from Jan 1st to Dec 1st, repeated many times because I have data for 18 years for 1701 different locations.

How can I separate out the data so that I create a cell array (or matrix) in which I have data for each site for each year saved separately? I am thinking it would be great to have 18 columns (for the 18 years) and then have each row as a different site.

Small subsets of the data for reference. All the variables are 5466921x1 cells:

## `Date`

Keeps going and repeats many times

```
729532
729533
729534
729535
729536
729537
729538
729539
729540
729541
729542
729543
729544
729545
729546
729547
729548
```

## `uID`

The site `id` that names each location I am considering. As you can see, since I only choose a small subset of dates, there's only one `uID`. If we were to go on long enough to cover all the dates for one site, we'd reach another `uID`.

```
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
'55-059-0019'
```

## `Data`

```
'9.8'
NaN
NaN
'6.2'
NaN
NaN
'11.3'
NaN
NaN
'23.2'
NaN
NaN
'23'
NaN
NaN
'3.4'
NaN
```

---

I tried the following code and I am getting a 1701x18 cell like I want with each cell being a 365x1 double, but I don't think it's right because when checking the dates for each individual cell, they are in order, but scrambled across several years. Each 365x1 double (or 366x1 double for leap years - which I'm not seeing either) should be from Jan 1 to Dec 31st for one year for one site. It may because I am not check for site IDs.

```
for year = 1997:2014 % Years under consideration
    dates = datenum(year, 01, 01):datenum(year, 12, 31); % For a whole year
    ind = intersect(Date3, dates);
    for i = 1:18
        for j = 1:length(uniqueuID)
            data_PM25{j,i} = Data(ind);
            date_PM25{j,i} = Date(ind);
        end
    end
end
```

Output for `data_PM25` would be something like this but with 18 columns and a lot more rows. The number of rows will vary in each column because each 365x1 is a site and there are different number of sites in each year:

```
<365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell>
<365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell>
<365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell>
<365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell>
<365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell>
<365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell><365x1 cell>
```

Each cell inside `data_PM25` would then have 365 doubles that show the value for each day. 
The date, `date_PM25` would be Jan 1 to Dec 31 for all of these cells with all the rows in the first column being 1997, the second column being 1998, all the way to 2014.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the final output should be?  I'm having a hard time understanding your problem description.  Also, `Data2` and `Date3` are undefined in your problem description.  What are these?

Comment: Does you `data` vector have a row for every date? Because then you can just pad and `reshape`?

Comment: @rayryeng The `Data2` and `Date3` were a typo - I changed it to match my question. I also added a bit about what the output would be.

Comment: @Dan I do have a row for every date. Could you write an example for reshaping this data set? The thing is that there isn't an exact number of sites for each year - There might be 3 sites in 1997 but 300 in 2014. So `reshape` may not work. I could be wrong about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a 3d data structure as follows (axis order may vary):

[image: How you should store data]

Like you mentioned, since some years are leap years you'd need to go through them and add a "Feb 29th" full of NaNs for all uID so that every data point has a coordinate like: `{year(1-18),uID(1-1701),day(1-366)}` that should provide both easy access and efficient storage.

---

Following your clarification in the comment:

> I do have a row for every date. The thing is that there isn't an exact number of sites for each year - There might be 3 sites in 1997 but 300 in 2014.

I would suggest storing the data in a `struct` where you have a uID vs Date array in each element, where the array (I'm saying array but this can also be another data structure, such as a [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html)) has a different size every time according to the amount of days and uIDs in that year.

Accessing the data will be done using: `dataStruct(year).dataTable{date,uID}`